# How to display html code trough a ruby form

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby

What I want is when I put html code that renders an image with a link in a form field that the image displays and not the code itself. I am not sure if this is even possible.

I found a couple of gems that kinda did that but only the

tags and 
 tags and stuff. Never to the level of this stuff.

How I render my form: 
    <%= food.image %>

The sort of code I want to put in my form field:

```
<a target="_blank"  href="https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0040QS3PO" rel="nofollow noreferrer"><img border="0" src="//ws-na.amazon-adsystem.com/widgets/q?_encoding=UTF8&MarketPlace=US&ASIN=B0040QS3PO&ServiceVersion=20070822&ID=AsinImage&WS=1&Format=_SL250_&tag=lovelytoulous-20" ></a><img src="//ir-na.amazon-adsystem.com/e/ir?t=lovelytoulous-20&l=am2&o=1&a=B0040QS3PO" width="1" height="1" border="0" alt="" style="border:none !important; margin:0px !important;" />
```

Is there a gem that I can use or is there an other way of doing this?
Thanks for heling me out!

Comment: Did you try something like `model.code.html_safe` in your view?

Comment: No, where should I put it in my view than?

Comment: What do you mean "code in a form field"? Do you want that to show up inside a `<textarea>`?

Comment: what is in food.image? file path?

Comment: What I mean by in a form field is that I can put the code on the website itself in a form field. food.image contains the content from that field. En makes it able to display on the right page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def image_tag_and_link_tag(source, options = {})
  options = options.symbolize_keys
  check_for_image_tag_errors(options)
  skip_pipeline = options.delete(:skip_pipeline)

  options[:src] = resolve_image_source(source, skip_pipeline)

  href_options = {}
  href_options[:href] = option[:src]
  href_options[:target] = '_blank'
  href_options[:rel] = "nofollow noreferrer"

  if options[:srcset] && !options[:srcset].is_a?(String)
    options[:srcset] = options[:srcset].map do |src_path, size|
      src_path = path_to_image(src_path, skip_pipeline: skip_pipeline)
      "#{src_path} #{size}"
    end.join(", ")
  end

  options[:width], options[:height] = extract_dimensions(options.delete(:size)) if options[:size]
  tag("img", options),tag("a",href_options)
end
```

### Above method will return two html tags "img" and "a"

Reference:https://www.rubydoc.info/github/rails/rails/ActionView%2FHelpers%2FAssetTagHelper:image_tag